# Return column A for which count(column A) = sum(column B)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A SQL Query to Return column A for which count(column A) = sum(column B) group by column A

Ex:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| ABC | 1 |
| ABC | -1 |
| DEF | 1 |
| DEF | 1 |
| GHI | 1 |
| GHI | -1 |
| GHI | -1 |
| GHI | -1 |

Output :
**DEF**
(Because count of DEF is equal to sum of its corresponding values in Column B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Having count(*)=sum([Column B])`

**Example**

```
Select [Column A] 
 From  YourTable
 Group By [Column A] 
 Having count(*)=sum([Column B])
```

**Results**

```
Column A
DEF
```